# Is “Reading strong” a popular alternative to “Read a lot more”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

NPR (October 23) reported that 8 in 10 Americans under the age of 30 have read a book in the past year in comparison to about 7 in 10 adults in general, American adults under the caption “America's Facebook generation is *reading strong*.”

I don’t think I’ve head “He / she reads strong,” or “He / she is a strong reader” very often.

OALED shows “strong” as the adjective to mean “great in number” in its 14th definition from the top – 1. having a great power.

Is “Read strong” a popular way of saying “Read a lot (or hard)”? 
Can I say “listen to strong,”
“Write strong,” or “eat / drink strong,” by the same token?

Comment: I think that the phrase *live strong*, from [Lance Armstrong's foundation,](http://www.livestrong.org/) bleeds over into other phrases in the U.S., such as *play strong.*

Comment: @Yoichi, I edited your title to match the exact phrase you're asking about.  I didn't understand the question until I read the phrase "reading strong".

Comment: @Yoichi: As you'll be able to see from some of the comments, the "acceptable range" of this usage varies from speaker to speaker. Some will only know/accept it in *"still **going** strong"*, which they'll see as a "frozen form". To others, it's effectively a "productive" form, which can be used with a wide variety of verbs. Not *all* verbs, but it would be hard for me to specify exactly which you can never use - and more crucially, ***why*** the construction isn't acceptable with those verbs. (Another incisive and intriguing question, by the way! :)

Comment: For reference, when i hear "strong reader", i think "someone who reads *well*".  The quantity of reading doesn't matter (except insofar as it serves as practice, of course).   "Reads strong" and "reading strong" just sound terribly awkward to me; "strong" is typically an adjective, not an adverb.  I live in the US (VA), if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NOAD says the phrase ***going strong*** means "continuing to be healthy, vigorous, or successful," with a usage example of *"the program is still going strong after twelve episodes."*  [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/strong#going-strong) defines it as "successful or healthy, and doing well", with these two examples:

> *The company's going strong and we expect to do even better next year.
>
>   My grandmother's 95 and still going strong*.

It's interesting that two of the three dictionary examples have the word *still*, as many of Xantix's example above also have.  That's often the sentiment conveyed: *it's now past the time you thought something would have faded into obscurity, yet it continues to endure*.  In the case of the NPR article, some might be surprised to find the Facebook generation – obsessed with 160-character texts and 140-character tweets – would be hardy readers of those old-fashioned relics we call *books*, yet statistics show that that generation is **reading strong**.

I think that the "going" in "going strong" can be replaced with other "-ing" verbs, and the expression retains the same meaning, although in a more localized sense.  So, the only way to make, say, *listening strong* "work" would be to devise a context where it seems surprising that some particular person or audience was still actively listening.  One possibility might be:

> *Even though Lawrence Welk has been dead for 20 years, his show continues to be aired on PBS, and his fans are still listening strong*.

Although I'd also agree with Bill Franke's comments above: the expression should be used sparingly, as it could easily be overused, and oftentimes there are probably better ways to convey the same sentiment:

> *Even though Lawrence Welk has been dead for 20 years, his show continues to be aired on PBS, with a band of faithful listeners tuning in each week*.

Comment: I don't disagree with the broad thrust of any answers so far, but I think this is probably the best summary of the position. And even though I wouldn't go so far as to say all modern usages are variants on the "frozen form" *"still going strong"*, the point about most usages involving *"still"* is important. There's invariably a sense of *continuing, and/or at a level beyond what might be expected*.

Answer (score 5):

I have only seen this construction with the "-ing" form of a verb.

A sentence like:

> I started singing yesterday, and I am still singing strong.

means that even though time has passed from when I started to sing, I am not now singing in a weak fashion.

So with regards to:

> "America's Facebook Generation is reading strong."

The "strong" could mean either:

- Individual readers have not weakened in the reading skills.
- Taken as a group, people are still reading in large numbers. (i.e. the Generation has not weakened in quantity of reading performed).

It would not be taken as meaning:

- The group is reading strong (hard) books such as "A Tale of Two Cities" or other classics.

You can use this with other verbs in the "-ing" form, for example:

> The party ends at four in the morning, till then, everyone will be dancing strong.
>
> With the election still a couple of weeks away, the candidates are campaigning strong.
>
> Even though she lost control of most of her muscles, she is still eating strong.
>
> Notwithstanding his brush with death, Lance Armstrong is living strong.

Comment: I've seen, heard, and used the idiom **still going strong**, but your "still singing strong" and "will be dancing strong" etc. all sound strange to me. I'd say **dancing away**, **campaigning hard**, **able to eat normally**, and "Lance is living strong** just because it's his motto. This construction must be some kind of localism.

Comment: @BillFranke: I won't argue that "dancing away" doesn't sound more natural than "dancing strong," or that "able to eat normally" wouldn't be an improvement over "eating strong;" nonetheless, I still think Xantix's examples work. Doing a search on Google books, e.g., I just found "Three songs after the opener, everyone was still dancing strong."

Comment: @Bill Franke: What J.R. said. I'm sure almost everyone would be happy with *"still going strong"* - and no-one would accept, say, *"still **waiting** strong"*. But I think it's putting a bit strong to suggest any usage going beyond what you personally are happy with "must be some kind of localism".

Comment: Ngram viewer shows no hits for "campaigning strong" or "dancing strong" or "eating strong" as discrete phrases. "Eating strong" almost always seems to precede a noun like "meat" or "cheese". I can imagine reading and understanding those phrases, of course, but I'd never write them myself. But that's just my personal preference, not a William Safire judgment.

Comment: @Xantix: I've upvoted because I agree your substantive point (*xxxx-ing strong* can be used with a wide range of "action" verbs). But I'm sure StoneyB is right that it's not a "gerund", so maybe you should edit that bit out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But J.R. found only 3 hits on Google books. I'd construe "localism" here as more than just something restricted to, say, Nottingham Forest, but also something restricted to a particular field, say, dance criticism. IOW: professional jargon or ballerina argot.

Comment: @Bill Franke: No-one is claiming words like *dancing, campaigning* are ***commonly*** used with strong. We're just saying such usage wouldn't seem exceptional to many speakers. I know there are lots of dups, but ["still campaigning strong"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22still+campaigning+strong%22&oq=%22still+campaigning+strong%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gets many hits on Google Internet, and *"still dancing strong"* gets many, many more.

Comment: Just corrected to "-ing" form. Interesting apparently Gerund is only used in English for the nouning of the verb by adding "-ing".  When I learned Italian, we called using the similar verb tense using the gerund. Like "Sto pensando". I'm glad I learned something new.

Comment: I didn't look for ***reading***, but I like this one: [Charles Elliott, Outdoor Life's Southern Editor, who, at 94 and still **writing strong**, has hundreds of big-game hunting trips under his belt...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22still+writing+strong%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I don't think that's "jargon", or any other kind of "regionalism". It's just a slightly uncommon (but to me, quite appealing) usage that occurs everywhere.

Comment: I understood “sing strong” “campaign strong” “dance strong” aren’t unusual. Then let me come back to my original question. Can I say “watch (TV) strong,” “hear / listen to (music) strong,” “drink (beer) strong,” “speak (nonsense) strong” in the same sense of today’s American youth “read stronger than elders” referring to specific number of 8 in 10 versus 7 in 10 as standard English expression?

Comment: Yoichi: I think your examples sound much more off - perhaps because watching TV, listening to music, and drinking beer are largely passive activities. Even looking at Xantix's examples, _dancing_ and _campaigning_ sound okay to me, but _eating_ sounded off a bit. This isn't a hard and fast rule, but I think that the more "active" the verb, the more it makes sense to use "strong." My example: "After 17 miles into the marathon, Paula was still running strong." I guess it depends on context, though, because, in your original article, you found "reading strong." Hmmm. Interesting.

Comment: @JR. So “Tom drives strong” and “He shoots strong,” “He plays golf strong” instead of “Tom drives a car quite a lot,” “He go out for shooting very often” and “He plays golf quite often” in showing numerical plenitude as in 8/10 youth reads vs. 7/10 elders read are acceptable?

Comment: @YoichiOishi Use the "-ing" form of the verb and you could probably get your examples to work. "Tom is still driving strong."  The sentence: "Jim turned 100 this month and is still playing golf strong." is probably about as good as you could do with playing golf, but the strong just doesn't seem to fit since it is far away from playing. If you rephrase, you could get "Jim is a professional golfer. He turned 100 and is still playing strong."

Comment: Yoichi: Not exactly. I agree with what @Xantix said. I've decided to elaborate in an answer, which can be found below. As for shooting, you might say, "Even after Tom had two fingers blown off in that hunting accident, he's still shooting strong." As I alluded to in my answer, somehow, there needs to be an element of surprise in the context.

Answer (score 2):

*Strong* has according to *OED 1* a history dating back to the 10th century of use as an adverb, in (apparently) the same wide range of senses as the adjective, and in both colloquial and formal contexts.

This use is not common today (I should guess it has been repressed by the schoolmarms); but it has survived in some idiomatic phrases; here are a few:

- **Still going strong** –of a person or machine, continuing to act with his/her/its wonted effect and efficiency. This one in particular is ‘strong’ enough to be extended to other verbs: *still writing strong, still playing strong*. (However, it's usually used of professional and public activities, not personal ones like *eating*.)
- **Come on strong** –to express oneself boldly or rashly in the attempt to make a strong first impression
- **Pitch it strong** –to make bold and unsubstantiated claims.

If I were charitable I would suggest that NPR's headline demonstrates a laudable historic sense of language and an admirable indifference to schoolmarmish strictures. I'm fond of NPR; but I don't believe it. I think this is just an awkward adaptation of *still going strong*, with the (to my ear) integral *still* omitted. But what the hey, it's only a headline.

I also think that pointing to the fact that "8 in 10 Americans under the age of 30 have read a book in the past year" as evidence that "America's Facebook Generation is reading strong" is, to say the least, pitching it rather strong.

Comment: I don't agree that *"still going strong"* is an "idiomatic fixed phrase". I accept it's not *that* common, but there are plenty of modern citations for *"still XXX-ing strong"* with other verbs. And incidentally, after a brief downturn in the 60s, [still going strong](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=still+going+strong&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) seems to be going [from strength to strength](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/144200.html).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Valid point. I will edit.

Comment: I did find [this one instance](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22still+eating+strong%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in a 100-year-old "Antarctic diary", but I think you're probably on the right track saying it's usually confined to *"professional and public activities"*. Specifically, perhaps, activities that might otherwise be expected to decline due to advancing age or some other "progressively limiting" factor - such as the implicit "education is going to the dogs" attitude which OP's citation refutes.